# How can I group by one field and sum fields in one object(output structure preserved) in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, aggregate, aggregation

I have two documents

```
_id:...
word: Casper
something: Object
     som1: 1
     som2: 2
```

```
_id:...
word: Casper
something: Object
     som1: 4
     som2: 5
```

I want to group and getting something like this:

```
_id: Object
    word: Casper
something: Object
     som1: 5
     som2: 7
```

The structure of the summed field should not be changed and remains to be an object.
But I'm new to mongo and don't know how to do it.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For grouping in Mongodb, you should use aggregate():

```
db.collectionName.aggregate([
    {$match:{
        "word": "Casper"
    }},
    {
        $group:
        {
            _id:{
               "word" : "$word"
            },
            "som1" : {$sum:"$something.som1"},
            "som2" : {$sum:"$something.som2"}
        }
    },
    {
        $addFields:{
            "something":{
                "som1": "$som1",
                "som2": "$som2"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project:{
            "som1":0,
            "som2":0
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: Yes, I know, but I want in the result som1, som2 as a fields of "something". Watch body of question. If I do, something: { "som1" : {$sum:"$something.som1"}, "som2" : {$sum:"$something.som2"} } doesn't work.

Comment: @FasterSol, now I got your question. Sorry for not paying enough attention. $addFields and $project should be used. I have modified the answer and let me know whether it works

Comment: If my answer helps you, can you please click the tick mark beside my answer to accept it@FasterSol

Comment: I have this problem, if you know solution, please answer https://stackoverflow.com/q/64661355/14541816